# Angular Universal and Guards Issue

Tags: angular

I have 3 routes.  I am using auth and admin guard in 2 routes only.  Now, when I load my first route (without guards) by clicking a link on homepage, all goes well.  But if i try to access it directly, I get following error.

I am sure it has something to do with routes and guards, so i need some help. 
 Please have a look over following and let me know what is wrong.

The strange part is that it works fine with **ng serve**, no issue at all, but only in case of angular universal ssr its throwing error.

> TypeError: provider.ngOnDestroy is not a function
>       at callProviderLifecycles (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:17395:18)
>       at callElementProvidersLifecycles (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:17363:13)
>       at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:17353:29)
>       at destroyView (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:18415:5)
>       at callViewAction (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:18541:13)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:18463:13)
>       at destroyView (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:18414:5)
>       at callViewAction (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:18541:13)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:18484:17)
>       at destroyView (D:\Exercises\Angular\productsApp\dist\server.js:18413:5)

```
 {
    path: 'product/:id',
    component: ProductDetailComponent    
  },
  {
    path: 'product/add',
    component: AddProductComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'product/edit/:id',
    component: EditProductComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the issue. Problem was that I was mocking quill editor to make it work on SSR.  The only thing which i had to add to that mocking QuillEditorComponent.

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {

    }
```